# Rules for 「みたいな感じ」（なっていってるみたいな感じ？）

Tags: word-choice, syntax, て-form

Was about to tweet something like this:

> ジェイクさんは野村君にとってどんどん指導者みたいになっていってるみたいな感じだね。

"It feels like Jake is gradually becoming more and more like a mentor to Nomura, doesn't it?"

...but a cursory Google shows that while there's of course a ton of results for 「になってるみたいな感じ」, and plenty for both 「いってるみたいな感じ」 and 「なっていってるみたい」, there's none at all for 「になっていってるみたいな感じ」, so I was wondering if there's something wrong with my usage here? It doesn't seem like this exact combination of elements should be so uncommon unless there was something wrong with it somehow. Any other corrections welcome, of course.

Comment: なっていってる is certainly not a most frequent type of phrasing, but I didn't expect zero.

Answer (score 1):

指導者みたいになっていってるみたいな感じだね is grammatically okay, but is unnecessarily long and roundabout. If I heard a native speaker say this, I would probably feel he's either joking or muddled.

At least you should drop one of the two みたい:

- 指導者みたいになっていってる感じだね
- 指導者になっていってるみたいな感じだね

This may be nit-picky, but I would usually expect なってってる instead of なっていってる in a casual sentence like this.

- 指導者みたいになってってる感じだね
- 指導者になってってるみたいな感じだね

Note that `verb/adjective + みたいな（感じ）` should be used sparingly because it's often considered as a typical obscure 若者言葉. `noun + みたいな感じ` is much safer.

Comment: Thanks! I figured it may be that it was just overly wordy. Does `verb/adjective + って感じ` carry the same 若者言葉 feeling as with `verb/adjective + みたいな感じ`?